# Running VBA functions in a specific order

Tags: excel, vba, function, execution

I am trying to get my worksheet to update every time I update a cell, but the functions declared need to be executed in order of the columns A-Z, how do I do this?

I have declared the functions in Module 1 as public functions, and they run perfectly whenever I select each cell and press <kbd>F2+Enter</kbd>, but if I try <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9</kbd> they execute invalid values. How do I make sure that my worksheet executes my VBA functions From cell A1-AX then B1-BX then C1-CX and so on?

Comment: `For C = 1 To 26` will call columns A to Z one after the other in proper sequence. If you want code to respond to a change in a cell you need to construct a `Worksheet_Change` event procedure which must be in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you have the cell. You can let the event procedure call your functions in Module1, perhaps in a loop as first explained, but a procedure in Module1 can't respond to events on a worksheet.

Comment: If you use UDF's as intended then Excel will manage the dependencies for you: you should not be using UDF's which need to be manually "managed" like you describe.